# HTML-документ не содержит объявления кодировки символов

Tags: java, html, ajax, spring

При передаче файла через форму на spring boot возникает ошибка: HTML-документ не содержит объявления кодировки символов. Если документ содержит символы, не входящие в диапазон US-ASCII, то в некоторых конфигурациях браузера в документе будет отображён искажённый текст. Кодировка символов страницы должна быть объявлена в документе или в протоколе передачи.

[image: 404 not found]

как подобное исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<form id="saveForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <h3>Название работы</h3>
  <input type="text" name="nameWork" maxlength="200" size="20" style="margin: 1%" required>
  <h3>Описание работы</h3>
  <textarea name="descriptionWork" cols="35" rows="10" style="margin: 1%" required></textarea>
  <h3>Загрузка файла:</h3>
  <input type="file" name="file" />

  <input id="bsave" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bsave').click(function() {
      var data = $("#saveForm").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/work/createWork",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $('#error1').html("Сохранен объект");
          $('#nameWork').html("Название: " + data.nameWork);
          $('#descriptionWork').html("Название: " + data.descriptionWork);
          $('#file').html("Название: " + data.file);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
          if (xhr.status == "500")
            $('#error1').html("<H1 style='color:red'>Ошибка на сервере</H1>");
          else $('#error1').html("<H1 style='color:red'>Ничего не найдено</H1>");
        }
      })
    })
  });
```

Comment: Вы лучше заголовки покажите, а не параметры.

Comment: @Visman добавил

Comment: Если сервер вам возвращает действительно тип `Content-Type 
text/html`, то пусть и кодировку указывает `Content-Type 
text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: @Visman подскажите пожалуйста где именно установить на сервере?

Comment: @Visman в pom.xml прописано вот так:  <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>